problem with moviepy, write_videofile raises WinErr6
I have a similar code that in the last part is identical to this, but only in this case write_videofile() raises exception
def taglia_video(self, cleaned_seconds):
        if not os.path.exists(self.cartella_output):
            os.makedirs(self.cartella_output)
        
        for i in range(len(cleaned_seconds)-1):
            start, end = cleaned_seconds[i], cleaned_seconds[i+1]
            print(f"Start: {start}, End: {end}")  # Debug
                
            video_path = os.path.join(self.cartella_video, self.video_file)
            output_path = os.path.join(self.cartella_output, f"sad_{os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(self.video_file))[0]}_{i+1}.mp4")
                
            video_clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)
            subclip = video_clip.subclip(start, end)
            subclip.write_videofile(output_path, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac") 
            subclip.close()
            video_clip.close()

write_videofile() raises this exception:

OSError: [WinError 6] Handle is invalid

Python 3.9
